# May we assume that $q_n=q_0=1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $$I=\int_a^b R(x)dx,$$
 where $R(x)$ is a rational function:
$$R(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$
with
$$P(x)=p_mx^m+p_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+p_1x+p_0,$$
$$Q(x)=q_nx^n+q_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+q_1x+q_0.$$

> If we evaluate $I$ under the normalisation $a=0$ and $b=\infty$, can we show that we may assume $q_n=q_0=1$?

I believe the transformation may help:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{t}{(2t+1)(t+1)^2}dt=\int_0^1\frac{x}{x+1}dx.$$

---

**Update**:
I also think that a change of vaiable of the form $ x \mapsto \lambda x$ may help.

Comment: I don't really get your question. If $q_0$ or $q_n$ is different, you get a different result.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1}\ dx\neq \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2x^2+2}\ dx$.

Comment: You can divide the numerator and denominator by a factor to eliminate one constant. You can eliminate another one by a rescaling of the integration variable. There are, of course, other transforms you can consider as well, e.g. $z = \frac{x}{1+x}$ will transform the integration  over z from 0 to 1.